# Does a reference to and instance create a new identity

Tags: php, variables

I have

```
$var1 = 123
$var2 = $var1
```

Does var2 reference to the identity of the instance 123 or does it copy the instance and creates a new reference in PHP?

Comment: That's easy to test: [https://eval.in/606588](https://eval.in/606588)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$var2 = $var1;` does not create a reference. It will indeed be copied.

If you do want a reference, you can do it like this:

`$var2 = &$var1;`

[Further reading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

Comment: That's weird. Compare [your code](https://eval.in/606589) with the one from [my comment](https://eval.in/606588). Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: Ah. Wrong format. `$var1 &= $var2` is a bitwise comparison! `=&` would work though :D

Comment: Thank you all that helped :)